# Macro to copy first section, and use next group of column that are the sales

Tags: excel, vba

now I am working with an excel file that have the sales of differents POS or store but I need to convert it from row to a kind of combination of row and column the idea is the following.

```
Original Excel has

Column a      Column b   Column C   Column D    Column E
Item          TacoBell   KFC        Pizza HUT   Dominos
Flour          10           8          11         9 
Egg            15           9          10         16    
Sugar          20           22         12         18

So the result excel need to be like

Column a      Column b   
Item          TacoBell  
Flour          10         
Egg            15         
Sugar          20         
Column a      Column b   
Item          TacoBell  
Flour          10         
Egg            15          
Sugar          20          
Column a       Column D    
Item           Pizza HUT   
Flour              11        
Egg                10           
Sugar              12         
Column a      Column E
Item            Dominos
Flour           9 
Egg             16    
Sugar           18
```

Please give any advice or guide me on doing it, I want to learn how to solve it.

Thanks on advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These instructions look like they might be a good first step in the right direction:
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/705-excel-convert-table-to-list.html#excel

If you need any further help implementing, just let me know.

Comment: Could you explain a little more, because I am checking and it seems that is similar to what I need only that on my case I think that I need to repeat first column the x time and tranpose the other column to row but not sure if the link shows how or maybe I need to understand a little more that macro.  But I will appreciate the advice